# Passing parameter to inner function in Python

Tags: python-3.x, scope, closures, python-decorators

While learning scopes in python, I come across the below simple code. My doubt is how can I pass the parameter to *outer_var* and *inner_var* in the function.

```
def outerfunc(outer_var):
    def innerfunc(inner_var):
        return outer_var * inner_var
    return innerfunc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, yeah, it's like @jonrsharpe said: it's because of closures.

Closures "close" around the state within a function that can be used later. Every time you run `outerfunc()`, the code will define a new version of `innerfunc()` that has access to `outer_var` that was passed in that time.

Closures are what make parameterized decorators work.